# Getting the Field Alias from a layer, from within a Map document

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, alias

I've got a very simple script, that loops through all the layers in a mxd and loops through the fields, and prints out the Alias Name for the field, but I am having some problems, it seems to be printing the field alias of the feature class (in SDE) not the value I have changed it to  in the map document...

Here's the script

```
import os, arcpy

myMxdFolder = r"D:\Maps"
count = 0

for mxd in os.listdir(myMxdFolder):
    #print mxd
    if mxd.endswith(".mxd"):
        #if mxd.startswith("COMPASS") or mxd.startswith("COLGIS"):
        if mxd.startswith("COLGIS_City_Occupiers.mxd"):
            mxdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(myMxdFolder + os.sep + mxd)
            filePath =  mxdoc.filePath
            print filePath
            for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxdoc):
                desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
                print lyr.name
                fields = desc.fields
                for field in fields:
                    print field.aliasName
```

The output is

```
OBJECTID
UPRN
ADDRESS
OCCUPIER
SHAPE
```

but the Aliases in the map document i have set it to are:

```
OBJECTID
HIGHLIGHT::UPRN
Address
Occupier
SHAPE
```

and that is what I was expecting, have a missed a trick somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think your answer can be found from this excerpt from this ESRI  Help Document on [Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000008000000)

> Not all layer properties are accessible through the Layer object.
>   There are many properties available in the ArcMap Layer Properties
>   dialog box that are not exposed to the arcpy scripting environment
>   (e.g., scale ranges, display properties, field aliases, symbology, and
>   so on). The UpdateLayer function allows you to replace all layer
>   properties available in ArcMap's Layer Properties dialog box using a
>   layer (.lyr) file that contains the customizations.

It specifically references `field aliases` and the `Layer Properties` dialog.

This might be something worth submitting an idea to the [ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaHome?c=09a300000004xET) site.